# Visual Studio design time and fixed-layout tables - your opinions

Tags: visual-studio-2008, design-time

I'm about to submit a bug to Microsoft.

The following html is displayed fine in a browser, but in VS designer it makes the entire page scrollable - as the table isn't clipped by the div:

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
    <table style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:1600px">1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Maybe you know similar bugs being already reported?
Or maybe you knows how to fight this?

Comment: I think either something is wrong with your code or your description.  ".. generates a scrollable area as like the overflow attribute is ignored" -- you have "overflow: scroll" on there -- shouldn't it scroll?

Comment: Yes, I said it bad. I mean that entire page becomes scrollable - table is not clipped by the div. You may want to try this markup in the VS2008 designer to see the actual behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is the Visual Studio Web Designer limitation. The corresponding request has been submitted to Microsoft:

[In the VS2008 web designer a fixed-layout table isn't clipped by a div with the overflow attribute set to "scroll" | Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=424421)